# can I only replace only 3 tires on a FWD van?

Tags: tires

I have a Toyota van  FWD- had to replace one tire last year (nail in sidewall). 
new tire - P225 / 60R17 Michelin Defender ( warranty 145,000km).
 It now has about 12km 
The other 3 tires need replacement!!
Is it ok to just replace the other 3 with the same Defender tire ???

Comment: Are you using "FWD" as Four Wheel Drive? FWD usually specifies Front Wheel Drive, so I'm just making sure.

Comment: It is front wheel drive ..

Answer (score 2):

Since this is only a two wheel drive vehicle, placing three new tires should not pose any issues for you if they are the same type/model as the ones which are coming off. Ensure you put two new tires on the front so that the drive tires are exactly the same (same wear amount). Not that it would create a huge issue, but different rolling widths may cause the differential in your transaxle to work a little harder than it would normally. Make sure you explain this to the tire shop as they will want to put two new tires on the back end ... just tell them, "I want two new tires on the front, with the used one in the rear."

There is one issue which may occur depending on the amount of tread difference between the new/old tires. That problem would be the wheel speed sensors. If the tread difference between the new/old tires is enough, it may trip the sensors and flash a fault on the dash (CES light). You won't know until it comes on though, if it's going to be an issue.